# google account sync on android 2.2 device

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I am implementing C2DM for push notification in an android application, it need at least
one log in Google account. I create a Google g mail account and login on device, but I am 
not able to sync it.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to sync your phone. You just need a Google account associated with the phone - Settings, Accounts, Add, and so forth.

Also note that it does *not* have to be the "sender account" - the one that you log on with on the server to send messages. In fact, it might even hurt if the account is the same. According to the docs, the C2DM sender account better be a dedicated one - not used for anything else other than sending C2DM's.